# Compute cumulative euclidean distances between subsequent pairwise coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization, distance

I have the following 2 arrays:

```
X = array([37., 42., 31., 27., 37.])

Y = array([52., 57., 62., 68., 69.])
```

I could alternatively combine them as follows with this:

```
XY = np.array((X, Y)).T
```

which produces

```
 ([[37., 52.],
   [42., 57.],
   [31., 62.],
   [27., 68.],
   [37., 69.]])
```

#### I want to compute the distances between all pairs of points

E.g. I want to do this:

```
(
np.linalg.norm(np.array([37, 52]) - np.array([42, 57]))
+ np.linalg.norm(np.array([42, 57]) - np.array([31, 62]))
+ np.linalg.norm(np.array([31, 62]) - np.array([27, 68]))
+ np.linalg.norm(np.array([27, 68]) - np.array([37, 69]))
+ np.linalg.norm(np.array([37, 69]) - np.array([37, 52]))
)
```

which then produces `53.41509195750892`

I have written a function that does so:

```
def distance(X, Y):
    N = len(X)
    T = 0
    oldx, oldy = X[-1], Y[-1]
    for x, y in zip(X, Y):
        T += np.linalg.norm((np.array([x,y])-np.array([oldx,oldy])))
        oldx = x
        oldy = y
    return T

print(distance(X, Y))
```

produces also `53.41509195750891`

#### I'm interested in knowing if there is a more elegant/efficient way to do this with numpy array operations.

**EDIT:** I'm sorry, the original example function I gave was wrong, now it should be correct

**EDIT:** Thanks everyone for the answers! Here is a benchmark with my array of size 50, it seems that Dani's answer is the fastest, even though Akshay's answer was faster for the size 5 array.

```
def distance_charel(X, Y):
    N = len(X)
    T = 0
    oldx, oldy = X[-1], Y[-1]
    for x, y in zip(X, Y):
        T += np.linalg.norm((np.array([x,y])-np.array([oldx,oldy])))
        oldx = x
        oldy = y
    return T

def distance_dani(X, Y):
    XY = np.array((X, Y)).T
    diff = np.diff(XY, axis=0, prepend=XY[-1].reshape((1, -1)))
    ss = np.power(diff, 2).sum(axis=1)
    res = np.sqrt(ss).sum()
    return res

def distance_akshay(X, Y):
    XY = np.array((X, Y)).T
    pairwise = pairwise = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(XY[:,None,:],XY[None,:,:])), axis=-1))
    total = np.sum(np.diag(pairwise,k=1))+pairwise[0,-1]
    return total

def distance_gwang(X, Y):
    XY = np.array((X, Y)).T
    return sum([sum((p1 - p2) ** 2) ** .5 for p1, p2 in zip(XY, XY[1:])])

def distane_andy(X, Y):
    arr = np.array((X, Y)).T
    return np.linalg.norm(arr - np.roll(arr, -1, axis=0), axis=1).sum()
```

then

```
print(distance_charel(X, Y))
print(distance_dani(X, Y))
print(distance_akshay(X, Y))
print(distance_gwang(X, Y))  # I think it misses the distance between last and first element
print(distane_andy(X, Y)) 
%timeit distance_charel(X, Y)
%timeit distance_dani(X, Y)
%timeit distance_akshay(X, Y)
%timeit distance_gwang(X, Y)
%timeit distane_andy(X, Y)
```

outputs

```
2586.769647563161
2586.76964756316
2586.7696475631597
2568.8811037431624
2586.7696475631597
2.49 ms ± 117 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
29.9 µs ± 191 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
385 µs ± 12.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.09 ms ± 4.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
31.2 µs ± 133 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**EDIT:** I accepted an answer Dani's answer now since I find his code the best (uses numpy vector operations, fairly readable, and fastest (by small margin)) for my situation. Thanks to all of you for answering!

**EDIT:** I updated the benchmark, using [280 coordinates](https://github.com/coin-or/jorlib/blob/master/jorlib-core/src/test/resources/tspLib/tsp/a280.tsp)

Comment: u want to calculate index 0 against 1,2,3,4... then index 1 against 2,3,4... or just the way you wrote it 
first one with second row, second row with third etc..

Comment: the way I wrote, first with second, second with third, etc, and then last with first again

Comment: You re not updating oldx, oldy so this computes all with the last

Comment: Yeah thats fixed now, the original function was messed up...

Comment: check my vectorized solution and the benchmarks for other answers compared.

Comment: Updated the question title to reflect the actual problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could compute the formula by *hand* in a vectorized fashion by using [diff](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), [power](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.power.html) and [sqrt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sqrt.html):

```
import numpy as np

# setup
X = np.array([37., 42., 31., 27., 37.])
Y = np.array([52., 57., 62., 68., 69.])
XY = np.array((X, Y)).T


# find the differences, prepend the last value at the front
diff = np.diff(XY, axis=0, prepend=XY[-1].reshape((1, -1)))

# raise to the power of 2 and sum
ss = np.power(diff, 2).sum(axis=1)

# find the square root and sum
res = np.sqrt(ss).sum()

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
53.41509195750891
```

The first step:

```
# find the differences, prepend the last value at the front
diff = np.diff(XY, axis=0, prepend=XY[-1].reshape((1, -1)))
```

computes `x1 - y1` and `x2 - y2`, the second step:

```
# raise to the power of 2 and sum
ss = np.power(diff, 2).sum(axis=1)
```

raises those values to the power of two, i.e `(x1 - y1)^2`, and also sum, finally:

```
# find the square root and sum
res = np.sqrt(ss).sum()
```

As it says find the square root.

To understand it better let's look at a smaller example:

```
# setup
X = np.array([37., 42.])
Y = np.array([52., 57])
XY = np.array((X, Y)).T

diff = np.diff(XY, axis=0)
# [[5. 5.]] (42 - 37) (57 - 52)

ss = np.power(diff, 2).sum(axis=1)
# [50.] 5^2 + 5^2

res = np.sqrt(ss).sum()
# 7.0710678118654755
```

Comment: Updated my benchmarks, well done :) I assumed the goal was to get all pairwise euclidean distances as the question title suggested and later fixed it to match the answer

Comment: For my case with the 280 element array, your solution is even faster (5μs faster) if you use ```np.linalg.norm(diff, axis=1).sum()```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it completely vectorized one-liner with ANY loops as the following with broadcasting -

1. First, `(5,1,2) broadcasted with (1,5,2) -> (5,5,2)`
2. Subtract with this broadcast to get `(5,5,2)`
3. Then square each element in the `(5,5,2)`
4. Sum over the last axis to get `(5,5)`
5. Finally, square root!

Next, you can just take the shifted diagonal array which holds the distance between `(1,2), (2,3) ...`. Sum that and since you want to add the distance back to first, add it to value of `[0,-1]`

[image]

```
#This get all pairwise distances calculated with broadcasting
pairwise = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(XY[:,None,:],XY[None,:,:])), axis=-1))

#This takes sum of the first diagonal elements instead of 0th
total = np.sum(np.diag(pairwise,k=1))+pairwise[0,-1]
print(total)
```

```
53.41509195750892
```

---

Another way you can do this is the following, but the above approach will still be faster -

```
np.sum(np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(np.diff(np.vstack([XY,XY[0]]), axis=0)), axis=-1)))
#The np.vstack adds the first coordinate into the array so that you can
#calculate the distance from the last to the first again
```

---

Benchmarks -

- **Akshay Sehgal** - 19.9 µs ± 2.53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
- **Gwang** - 21.5 µs ± 1.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
- **ombk** - 60.4 µs ± 5.72 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
- **Dani Mesejo** - 16.4 µs ± 6.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
- **Andy L** - 17.6 µs ± 3.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

As expected, numpy vectorization always rules the day! Gj Dani!

Comment: I don't think this matches the expected output

Comment: could you please also timing mine?

Comment: Done, added it to the list, yours is super close to Dani's solution

Answer (score 3):

You may use `np.roll` together with `np.linalg.norm` and `sum`

```
#arr = np.stack([X,Y], axis=1)

arr = np.array((X, Y)).T #as suggested in the comment

Out[50]:
array([[37., 52.],
       [42., 57.],
       [31., 62.],
       [27., 68.],
       [37., 69.]])

In [52]: np.linalg.norm(arr - np.roll(arr, -1, axis=0), axis=1).sum()
Out[52]: 53.41509195750892
```

Comment: very elegant solution, probably the most readable so far imo! btw I just checked, your solution is faster (for a 280 coordinate array at least), if you use ```arr = np.array((X, Y)).T``` instead of the way you're doing it.

Comment: @charel-f: it is interesting finding. I changed it as your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#preparation:
x = np.array([37., 42., 31., 27., 37.]) 
y = np.array([52., 57., 62.,68.,69.]) 
xy = np.array((x, y)).T 

def euclidean_distance(p1, p2): 
     return sum((p1 - p2) ** 2) ** .5
```

You can do it more elegantly using functional programming.
Here, you want to `reduce` over the list of pairs of successive elements in `xy`:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
reduce(add, [euclidean_distance(p1, p2) for p1, p2 in zip(xy, xy[1:])])
## 36.41509195750892
```

`reduce` over a list `[1, 2, 3, 4, ..., k]`
by applying a diadic function `func(a, b)` makes this:
 `func( ... func(func(func(func(1, 2), 3), 4), 5) ..., k)`.

@DaniMesejo pointed out `reduce(add, lst)` is just `sum(lst)`.

So it is even much simpler:

```
sum([euclidean_distance(p1, p2) for p1, p2 in zip(xy, xy[1:])])
```

The best trick here is actually the `zip(xy, xy[1:])`
which creates from a list `[1, 2, 3, 4, ..., k]`
the pairs: `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), ... (k-1, k)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

X = np.array([37., 42., 31., 27., 37.])

Y = np.array([52., 57., 62., 68., 69.])
XY = np.array((X, Y)).T    
sum1 = euclidean(XY[0],XY[-1])


for i in range(len(XY)-1):
    sum1 += euclidean(XY[i],XY[i+1])
```

This should do it, start with your sum with the hardest term. Then iterate on the easier ones. Add them all together.

as a check `euclidean(XY[0],XY[1]) = 7.0710678118654755` same value that you provided.

Comment: hmm I'm not sure this works. will check though and will let you know. btw the function I initially gave was wrong, now its correct (I update oldx and oldy in the loop)

Comment: It works hehe 
unless im missing something in ur statement

Comment: Ok your for loop works, but it is very similar to mine, I would like to avoid this for loop and instead use numpy vector operations if possible

Answer (score 0):

```python
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([[37., 42., 31., 27., 37.],
   ...:                    [52., 57., 62., 68., 69.]]).T.rename(columns={0:"X", 1:"y"})
   ...: df
Out[2]: 
      X     y
0  37.0  52.0
1  42.0  57.0
2  31.0  62.0
3  27.0  68.0
4  37.0  69.0

In [3]: from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
   ...: np.sum([euclidean(df.iloc[i], df.iloc[i+1]) for i in range(len(df)-1)])
Out[3]: 36.41509195750892
```